# strip_tags and htmlentities

Tags: php

Should I use `htmlentities` with `strip_tags`?

I am currently using `strip_tags` when adding to database and thinking about removing `htmlentities` on output; I want to avoid unnecessary processing while generating HTML on the server.

Is it safe to use only `strip_tags` without allowed tags?

Comment: @Beck I deleted my answer because on closer look, I'm not sure whether `strip_tags()` without allowed tags is actually unsafe. I started a specific question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788527/is-strip-tags-vulnerable-to-scripting-attacks).

Comment: Ok mate :) I think i'll have to find a proper generated pages caching tool for myself while you are deciding is it's safe or not. :P

Comment: Yeah! :) For reference, the HTML purifier link from my question: http://htmlpurifier.org/ but why do you want to use `strip_tags()` over `htmlspecialchars()` in the first place, any special reason?

Comment: strip_tags removes only complete tags as i noticed. So the rest is left untouched. And i wanted to keep data the same as user typed it in the first place, but safe for the rest end users and my website templates.

Comment: Plus if it's surely safe, then htmlentities is not required at the final output and it's used pretty widely in my templates. Without caching it's eating server resources.

Comment: @Beck but the amount of server resources consumed by doing a `htmlentities()` on output is minuscule. I can't imagine it making anything noticeably slower. `htmlentities()` would keep things *exactly* as the user typed them in, including `<` and `>`, would that not be the vastly superior approach?

Comment: The thing is, that i actually didn't used htmlentities earlier. Because i was really lame at that time :D
And now i need to decide if i really need it or not. Because i'm not sure if it's safe.

Comment: @Beck I'd say use it - from what you say, it will probably serve your users better than strip_tags().

Comment: It seems the only unwanted feature strip_tags have is that it really strips some part of text after <notTag user input. But it's not stripping in these cases: test3 awefawef> , < test4 awefawe> , < test6 awefawef >

Comment: Ok then i'll have to overview all my templates :)

Answer (score 15):

First: Use the escaping method only as soon as you need it. I.e. if you insert something into a database, only escape it for the database, i.e. apply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (or `PDO->quote` or whatever database layer you are using). But don't yet apply any escaping for the output. No `strip_tags` or similar yet. This is because you may want to use the data stored in the database someplace else, where HTML escaping isn't necessary, but only makes the text ugly.

Second: You should not use `strip_tags`. It removes the tags altogether. I.e. the user doesn't get the same output as he typed in. Instead use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). It will give the user the same output, but will make it harmless.

Answer (score 11):

`strip_tags` will remove all HTML tags:

```
"<b>foo</b><i>bar</i>" --> "foobar"
```

`htmlentities` will encode characters which are special characters in HTML

```
"a & b" --> "a &amp; b"
"<b>foo</b>" --> "&lt;b&gt;foo&lt;/b&gt;"
```

If you use `htmlentities`, then when you output the string to the browser, the user should see the text as they entered it, not as HTML

```
echo htmlentities("<b>foo</b>");
```

Visually results in: <b>foo</b>

```
echo strip_tags("<b>foo</b>");
```

Results in: foo

Comment: Mate i know what they are doing. I'm asking is strip_tags enough to output data without using htmlentities?

Comment: Guess i must start to think about caching generated pages. Can someone suggest good caching tool for such task? :)

Comment: @Beck: well, what's your desired result? Do you want there to be no HTML? Are you only concerned about SQL injection?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `htmlentities` as this will allow you to insert the string, as is, into the database. Yhis is no good for account details or forums.

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` for inserting data into the database, and `strip_tags` for receiving data from the database and echoing out to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this one and see the differences:

```
 <?php

  $d= isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : "empty argv[1]".PHP_EOL;
  echo  strip_tags(htmlentities($d)) . PHP_EOL;
  echo  htmlentities(strip_tags($d)) . PHP_EOL;

 ?>
```

open up cmd or your terminal and type something like following;

```
  php your_script.php "<br>foo</br>"
```

this should get what you want and safe !