# Data Id is not showing Why is that?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

here's my code why is that the data for price is showing while the ID is not? Help please

```
<?php
include"Connection.php";
$dTime = time();
$myValue = $_REQUEST['dValue'];
echo "The time is: {$dTime}<br/>
The choice is {$myValue} ";

$sql = "Select * from product where NAME = '{$myValue}'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

        $price = $row['PRICE'];
        $id = $row['ID'];
        echo "PHP $price";
        echo "$id";

$sql2 ="INSERT INTO `starbucks`.`order_details` (`ID`, `ORDER_ID`, `PRODUCT_ID`, `QTY`) VALUES ('2', '1', '$id', '1');";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
?>
```

Comment: Try a `var_dump` on $row

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing the structure of your 'product' table. Can you run `SHOW COLUMNS FROM PRODUCT` on your database? Edit: It's probably the curly brackets though rather than the data structure.

Comment: Hi there [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Why on earth would you do `echo "$id";` and not `echo $id;`. Go learn some PHP basics, please.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT forget the braces, otherwise only one line of code will execute.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $price = $row['PRICE'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    echo 'PHP ', $price; // do not use variable concatenation or double quotes if you can
    echo $id; // no need to wrap a variable with quotes for printing it
}
```

---

Do NOT forget to [escape user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php), otherwise you will be prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286267/php-xss-question-clarification) attacks.

```
$myValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['dValue']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any curly brackets delineating your while loop, so it is only running the line `$price = $row['PRICE'];` for each row. Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        $price = $row['PRICE'];
        $id = $row['ID'];
        echo "PHP $price";
        echo "$id";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using curly braces for while loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

it will only execute 1 line after this not the second one