# Universal mysql escaping and html tags stripping in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: the ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/php-the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)

Is there a way to mysql escape all variables in my code before sending it to the database as well as stripping all HTML tags? I don't want to go to each variable to do that, so I wonder if there is a universal way to instruct my PHP pages (maybe put something in the header?) to do that before processing mysql_query calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this - it's bound to break your data. Apply escaping where  needed, when it's needed.

Comment: No, not in the way you are thinking. You can use a mysql wrapper like [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to handle escaping for you implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) when querying your database to escape values in your query.

Answer (score 0):

There is, but that's just wrong. The escpaing should happen at the db layer, not at the input. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286267/php-xss-question-clarification/7286416#7286416).

And to answer the question, you can use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) on the $_REQUEST variable.