# preg_replace html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to delete all html tags (including their attributes such as class, src, id, etc.) on a string but I would like to retain `<ul>`,`<li>` and `<br />` tags. How will I accomplish this?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a library such as html purifier:

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Be wary of using strip_tags() with an argument:

[Is strip_tags() vulnerable to scripting attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788527/is-strip-tags-vulnerable-to-scripting-attacks)

http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Comment: +1 For the warning. The user may find a simple use of `strip_tags()` to be less appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and pass in allowable tags. No need to re-invent the wheel. There are some security concerns with this method which might prevent you from using it. Please consider [@Denis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002665/preg-replace-html-tags/6002714#6002714) if this is the case.

Comment: That's not a good solution, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788527/is-strip-tags-vulnerable-to-scripting-attacks

Comment: @Denis It may be harmful, but then again we aren't told exactly how it will be used and in which way. There are many uses of this function that would be legitimate and provide no security risks whatsoever. Unfortunately the OP didn't provide sufficient details for us to make that decision.

Comment: @acidpaul Please give special attention to Denis' comments as well. Glad to see we could help you.

Answer (score 3):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

strip_tags($text, '<ul><li><br>');

Answer (score 1):

There you go, bro

```
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

$text = strip_tags($text, '<ul><li><br>');
```

Do not use preg_replace, it cost u lot memory.