# Am using my sanetize right

Tags: php, javascript, xss, sql-injection

I need to store data in a mysql table then output it to the user.

I am sanetizing "name" and "comment"

On name im using strip_tags and trim, then storing it with stmt prepare/bind_param.

And on "comment" im using nl2br/htmlspecialchars then storing it with stmt prepare/bind_param,
since users must be able to hit enter/linebreak.

So is this enough to protect me against XSS/SQL-injections?

Thanks

Comment: That one doesnt mention anything about xss

Comment: So, do a search and find one that does. It's not hard to find.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHYXHIXTdtc

Answer (score -1):

strip_tags hmmm.. [look on other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788527/is-strip-tags-vulnerable-to-scripting-attacks)

Moreover you are changing user input, I think it's better to show complete input (safely)

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

and [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623236/htmlspecialchars-vs-htmlentities-when-concerned-with-xss)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that HTML Purifier mentioned in that post

Comment: strip tags is only vulnerable if used to filter, not to strip all.

Comment: using strip_tags only as in the question will break on many cases and it is not safe https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.