# How to use the combination of strip_tags and htmlentities on the results of a PHP form?

Tags: php, html, encoding, html-encode, strip-tags

I've built a CMS that allows users to upload data through a webform. And i'm trying to find a way i can use both `html_entities()` and `strip_tags` on the results of the form before i insert them to my database.   
  Obviously this code doesn't work right:

```
    $name_article  = $_POST["name"];
    $add_to_db     = htmlentities(strip_tags($name_article,"<br/><br>"));
```

It results in encoding the **wanted** tags in html entities, like `<br/>` into `&lt;br/&gt;` How do you avoid this?

PS: watched the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788314/php-strip-tags-and-htmlentities) didn't get a valid answer.

Comment: I think elaborating on **wanted** and **not wanted** in your situation should help your question

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Please show a typical input and what would be the desired end result.

Comment: There are a few things here: Why do you want html_entities() to be run before DB insert? Why do you even want HTML in your database (though I accept it's a common thing to do)? What tags do you want? And, really, what are you actually trying to do?