# What is better for user experience strip_tags or htmlentities in php?

Tags: php, html, html-entities, strip-tags

I have a web form that asks users for article name and the author of article. At the php backend in order to prevent malicious scripts I have two options - Use strip tags to prevent any tags user gives or escape the input via htmlentities.

Consider both factors security and better user experience. What should I go forward with ?

Comment: Use strip_tags. You're probably not interested in the HTML markup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strip\_tags and htmlentities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788314/strip-tags-and-htmlentities)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want those characters to show.

If you're just dealing with author names and article titles, you're probably safe using `strip_tags()` but if you're taking the whole article, it could contain characters like `>`, `<` and `/` so I'd suggest `htmlentities()`.

Comment: even if i'm taking the whole article the < ,> will not show up in their original form. They'll come as html code.

Comment: Yes, and when you render `&lt;` to the page via `echo`, you'll get `<`.